# Varying Item Types Within the Same Column of IG

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex

I currently have an interactive grid within my oracle apex application with two columns that displays user data.  The right column needs to be editable and I want some of the fields within this column to be text fields and others to be a select list.

From my research I feel like this is possible if you use some embedded HTML within the source SQL query for the IG, but so far I have had no luck with any progress.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.